# How do I automatically back up a deployed meteor database?

Tags: shell, meteor

I have backed up the data from my deployed meteor database successfully using the following commands:

meteor mongo --url MYSITE.meteor.com

mongodb://client:PASSWORD@HOST:27017/MYSITE_meteor_com

mongodump -u client -h HOST:27017 -d MYSITE_meteor_com -p PASSWORD

but I'm thinking it must be possible to write a shell script to do automate this. I assume that I could use grep to pull off the variables from the url returned from the first command, and then enter them into the second command.

Could anyone who knows more about shell scripts advise on how they would approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example in bash(untested cause i dont use app.meteor.com):

```
#!/bin/bash

# You might want to change these:
SITE = 'MYSITE.meteor.com'
CLIENT = 'my_usrname'
PASS = 'my_1337_pwd'
DUMPDIR = '/home/example/backups/'
NOW = $(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M")

#Some fu to convert dots to underscores:
SITE_UNDERSCORE=${SITE//./_}


meteor mongo --url $SITE

mongodb://$CLIENT:$PASS@$SITE:27017/$SITE_UNDERSCORE

mongodump -u $CLIENT -h HOST:27017 -d $SITE_UNDERSCORE -p PASSWORD >    $DUMPDIR/$SITE_UNDERSCORE.$NOW.mongodb
```

Comment: The use of variables is certainly a sensible suggestion - but I need to assign the values returned by the first call: meteor mongo --url $SITE to those variables.

Comment: you mean like so: `NEWVAR=$(meteor mongo --url $SITE)` ?

Comment: The first command returns a temporary PASSWORD, for example, which I need to capture and assign to the second command. But the password is embedded in quite a complex string which needs to be parsed. That is why I am thinking grep is the way to go.

Comment: I think the commandline tool `sed` is more suitable for this thing, a tutorial about it can be found here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-regular-expressions.htm